# Display text in unity onTrigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to display a text in unity by a trigger, but it isnt working, this is my code. I have a collider with "Is Trigger" activated, the tags are ok, i dont know what its happening...

```
    public class LaptopTriggerCollider : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject UiObject;
    public GameObject cube;

    void Start()
    {
        UiObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {

        if (other.tag.Equals("player"))
        {
            UiObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
    void Update()
    {

    }
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        UiObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try to debug by putting a log statement in OnTriggerEnter function

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Debug.Log("Is this even being triggered?");
    if (other.tag.Equals("player"))
    {
        UiObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

I presume it won't print in console, reason could be that you are missing a rigidbody in the collision.
A rigidbody is a must for collision or trigger events to be generated in Unity.

Comment: Tried that, but stills do not function...

Comment: Does the Debug statement print?

Answer (score 0):

Instead `tag.Equals` use `CompareTag`

```
if(other.CompareTag("player"))
{
   UiObject.SetActive(true);
}
```

[CompareTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html)